# error message when using the cropping perspective correction tool in photoshop 2019

Tags: photoshop-effects

I get the following error message when trying to use the cropping perspective correction tool:
"impossible to use the cropping perspective correction tool because the image contains unsupported layer types"

Is there any idea to get around this problem?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You may need to flatten the image first.  Try that.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer, see the answer of cahel2002 at the following link:
https://forum.hardware.fr/hfr/Graphisme/Cours/photoshop-probleme-perspective-sujet_27563_1.htm

Comment: While the link may answer the question - for people who can read French - if the link ever disappears, so does the answer. Please take the time to summarise the solution in here, in English, for future searchers.